# How do you `get` the current state from a a state monad that is part of a product monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am building some product monads from Control.Monad.Product package. For reference, the product monad type is:

```
newtype Product g h a = Product { runProduct :: (g a, h a) }
```

Its monad instance is:

```
instance (Monad g, Monad h) => Monad (Product g h) where
    return a = Product (return a, return a)
    Product (g, h) >>= k = Product (g >>= fst . runProduct . k, h >>= snd . runProduct . k)
    Product (ga, ha) >> Product (gb, hb) = Product (ga >> gb, ha >> hb)
```

source: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-products/3.0.1/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Product.html

**Problem I**

I build a simple monad that is a product of two `State Int` Monads, However, when I try to access the underlying state next:

```
ss :: Product (State Int) (State Int) Int
ss = do 
  let (a,b) = unp $ P.Product (get,get) :: (State Int Int,State Int Int)  
  return 404
```

You see `get` just creates another `State Int Int`, and I am not sure how to actually get the value of the underlying state, how might I do that? Note I could potentially `runState` `a` and `b` to get the underlying value, but this solution doesn't seem very useful since the two states' initial values must be fixed a priori.

**Question II.**

I would really like to be able to create a product monad over states of different types, ie:

```
ss2 :: Product (State Int) (State String) ()
ss2 = do 
  let (a,b) = unp $ P.Product (get,get) :: (State Int Int,State Int String)  
  return ()
```

But I get this type error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: (State Int Int, State String String)
      Actual type: (StateT Int Identity Int,
                    StateT String Identity Int)
```

Because I presume the two `get` must return the same type, which is an unfortunate restriction. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use a state monad with a product of your states:

```
m :: State (Int, String) ()
```

Then you can run an operation that interacts with one of the two fields of the product using `zoom` and `_1`/`_2` from the `lens` library, like this:

```
m = do
    n <- zoom _1 get
    zoom _2 $ put (show n)
```

To learn more about this technique, you can read my [blog post on lenses](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) which goes into much more detail.

Comment: That totally works! I guess the real problem I am trying to solve is how to compose a pair of transformers with different underlying monads, ie, `composeT :: t m a -> t m' a -> t (Product m m') a`, and then run the product such that m and m' can have its own effects. I tried Product Monad as a possible solution, but does using lenses work in this case as well? Or is there another solution my actual problem, it seems like it would come up a lot ...

Comment: @chibro2 You can't do it solely using the `MonadTrans` type class . However, there's no reason you can't write your own type class for such a purpose.  I recommend you read [this paper about `Applicative`s](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html), specifically the part about the `Monoidal` class (which is equivalent to the `Applicative` class).  It looks like what you want is a higher-order `Monoidal` type class.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done the way you want. Suppose there would be a way how to get the current state out of the left monad. Then you'd have a function of type

```
getLeft :: Product (State a) (State b) a
```

which is isomorphic to `(State a a, State b a)`.

Now we can choose to throw away the left part and run only the right part:

```
evalState (snd (runProduct getLeft)) () :: a
```

So we get an inhabitant of an arbitrary type `a`.

In other words, the two monads inside `Product` are completely independent. They don't influence each other and can be run separately. Therefore we can't take a value out of one and use it in another (or both of them).